# Node.js Mariasql Count result not useful

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I don't become a useful result from the count query.

Here is my wonderful code.

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;
var Client = require('mariasql');

var c = new Client();
c.connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'xx',
  db: 'node'
});


c.query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Addresses;")
.on('result', function(res) {
res.on('row', function(row) {
console.log(row); // The Problem row.id, row.Count or row.Count.id don't works
})
.on('error', function(err) {
console.log('Result error: ' + inspect(err));
})
.on('end', function(info) {
console.log('Result finished successfully');
});
})
.on('end', function() {
console.log('Done with all results');
}); 
c.end();
```

My output is

> [cseipel@myhost test]$ node counter.js  { 'COUNT(id)': '6' }  Result
>   finished successfully> Done with all results

but i need only a "6" by line two

Answer (score 0):

Try including a more useful column name in your query, for example: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS Count FROM Addresses`. Then inside the 'row' event you should have a `row.Count` value.